# Ordered set and ordered field

Tags: order-theory, ordered-fields

To be clear, let me use "$=$" to mean the same element in a set, and "$\sim$" to mean neither "$>$" nor "$<$" in an order.

In an ordered set even if $x\ne y$, we can still set $x\sim y$, right?

If yes, is it true that for an ordered field, under the extra conditions, viz.,

$$x+z<y+z \hspace{1cm} \text{if} \hspace{1cm}y<z$$
$$xy>0 \hspace{1cm} \text{if} \hspace{1cm} x>0 \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} y>0$$

we can prove that
$$x\sim y \hspace{1cm}\text{iff}\hspace{1cm} x=y$$

Comment: no, if $x$ and $y$ are different elements, then you can not prove that $x=y$. If you can prove that $x=y$, then of course $x$ and $y$ are the same elements. It is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You might want to specify what sort of ordering you mean. See -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_order_structures_in_mathematics . Also you might want to use `=` for "the same" and `~` to mean "neither `x < y` nor `x > y`". Then your first statement could mean (for instance) in a weakly (partially/quasi...) ordered set, we can have `x ~ y`. An "ordered field" however, is usually taken to be a totally ordered field -- so without extra conditions, `x~y => x=y`. "Partially ordered fields" have been studied, but you have to specify what conditions you mean.

Comment: @shaunc, I checked wiki, seems that it's also not possible for partial order, due to the antisymmetry axiom. I think it's possible in quasi-order as you mentioned (which is just another name of preorder?).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in almost all circumstances it is the case that $x = y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are "the same" (semantically) or "completely interchangeable in all circumstances" (operationally). Of course, in *your* theory you can define equality whatever way you want, but then you should probably use a different symbol since otherwise everybody would be confused.